# Currying subtraction

Tags: haskell, coding-style

If we want to map a function that increases every element of a range by 1, we could write

```
map (\x -> x + 1) [1..5]
```

but I guess most people would just go for

```
map (+1) [1..5]
```

instead. But this obviously doesn't work with (-1) since that's negative one.

So the first thing that came to mind was

```
map (+(-1)) [1..5]
```

which would make sense considering how subtraction is defined in the Prelude (`x - y               = x + negate y`), but looks a bit odd to me. I then I came up with

```
map (flip (-) 1) [1..5]
```

This somehow looks better to me, but is maybe a bit too complicated.

Now I know this no big deal, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a more obvious way to write this? If not, which of the 2 ways would you prefer? I'm really just asking because often it's small details like this that make your code more idiomatic and hence pleasant for other developers who have to read it.

**Solution**

Now that I got a couple of answers, I think my personal favorite is

```
map (subtract 1) [1..5]
```

followed by

```
map pred [1..5]
```

mostly because the first one is really explicit and nobody needs to guess/look up what `pred` means (predecessor).

Comment: A small note: the problem isn't currying, it's the operator section syntax.  `(-) 1` is a (syntactically valid) way to partially apply the curried `-` function.

Comment: I was struggling with a title for this and couldn't come up with anything better. Also `map ((-) 1) [1..5]` doesn't work, hence the version with flip.

Comment: If they are Integral, and you just want to subtract 1, why not `map pred`

Comment: @Grazer Because I didn't know about it, hence the question if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: See also http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Unary_operator

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the `subtract` function instead of `-` if you want to right-section subtraction:

```
map (subtract 1) [1..5]
```

Answer (score 9):

Since `-` is both the infix subtract and the prefix negate, you can't use the  `(*x)` (where * is an infix operator and x a value) syntax for `-`. Luckily Prelude comes with `negate` and `subtract`, which is `\x -> -x` and `\x y -> y-x` respectively, so that you may use those where you need to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 3):

After many years since this question was asked, in GHC 9 we now have
the [`LexicalNegation`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/lexical_negation.html?highlight=lexicalnegation#extension-LexicalNegation) extension which allows the section `(- 1)`, as long we use whitespace to separate the minus sign from the number.

Indeed, after enabling the extension, we have:

```
> map (subtract 1) [1..5]       -- still works, of course
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

> map (- 1) [1..5]              -- with whitespace
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]                 -- (- 1) is now a section

> map (-1) [1..5]               -- no whitespace
*error*                         -- (-1) is now a negative literal
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `map (\x -> x - 1) [1..5]` transmits the programmer's intention better, since there's no doubt about what is being subtracted from what. I also find your first solution, `map (+(-1)) [1..5]`, easy to read too.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like `subtract` because it's confusingly backwards. I'd suggest

```
minus :: Num n => n -> n -> n
minus = (-)
infixl 6 `minus`
```

Then you can write

```
map (`minus` 1) [1..5]
```

Comment: I prefer just `(+(-1))`. The trick with the new name is nice, but it takes up a valuable name. 

Too bad ``(`-` 1)`` is invalid syntax.