# The difference between +1 and -1

Tags: function, haskell, operators, prefix

```
> :t (+1)
(+1) :: Num a => a -> a

> :t (-1)
(-1) :: Num a => a
```

How come the second one is not a function? Do I have to write `(+(-1))` or is there a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454559/currying-subtraction/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `(-1)` is interpreted as negative one, however `(+1)` is interpreted as the curried function `(\x->1+x)`.

In haskell, `(a **)` is syntactic sugar for `(**) a`, and `(** a)` is `(\x -> x ** a)`. However `(-)` is a special case since it is both a unary operator (negate) and a binary operator (minus). Therefore this syntactic sugar cannot be applied unambiguously here. When you want `(\x -> a - x)` you can write `(-) a`, and, as already answered in [Currying subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454559/currying-subtraction/), you can use the functions `negate` and `subtract` to disambiguate between the unary and binary `-`  functions.

Comment: "Negation is the only prefix operator in Haskell" http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html

Comment: @mjg123, I think writing "the unary operator" rather then "a unary operator" here only makes it harder to get the message which is "its both unary and binary." Therefor I think I will leave it as it is. =D

Answer (score 6):

> Do I have to write (+(-1)) or is there a better way?

I just found a function called `subtract`, so I can also say `subtract 1`. I find that quite readable :-)

Comment: +1 `subtract` was made specifically for use in sections. [Haskell 2010 / Expressions # Sections](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5) "Because - is treated specially in the grammar, `(- exp)` is not a section, but an application of prefix negation, as described in the preceding section. However, there is a `subtract` function defined in the Prelude such that `(subtract exp)` is equivalent to the disallowed section. The expression `(+ (- exp))` can serve the same purpose."

Answer (score 1):

`(-1)` is negative one, as others have noted. The subtract one function is `\x -> x-1`, `flip (-) 1` or indeed `(+ (-1))`.

`-` is treated as a special case in the [expression grammar](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#operators). `+` is not, presumably because positive literals don't need the leading plus and allowing it would lead to even more confusion.

**Edit**: I got it wrong the first time. `((-) 1)` is the function "subtract from one", or `(\x -> 1-x)`.

Comment: the usual "subtract one" function is just `subtract 1`