# Understanding the functions elem and isInfixOf

Tags: haskell

A while ago I've asked a question about the function `elem` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619217/compare-lists-in-haskell), but I don't think the answer is fully satisfactory. My question is about the expression:

```
any (`elem` [1, 2]) [1, 2, 3]
```

We know `elem` is in a backtick so `elem` is an infix and my explanation is:

```
1 `elem` [1, 2] -- True
2 `elem` [1, 2] -- True
3 `elem` [1, 2] -- False
```

Finally it will return `True` since it's `any` rather than `all`. This looked good until I see a similar expression for `isInfixOf`:

```
any (isInfixOf [1, 2, 3]) [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2]]
```

In this case a plausible explanation seems to be:

```
isInfixOf [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 4] -- True
isInfixOf [1, 2, 3] [1, 2]       -- False
```

I wonder why they've been used in such different ways since

```
any (elem [1, 2]) [1, 2, 3]
```

will give an error and so will

```
any (`isInfixOf` [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2]]) [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase the question. Are you asking for the difference between `elem` and `isInfixOf`? That should be clear from the definitions/documentation.

Comment: @larsmans Not exactly. I know what they are but I'm asking how they can be used and why

Comment: Consider using `flip elem [1, 2]` instead.

Comment: thx, that's the original version. As I were saying, my question mainly concerns how and why rather than what. It's solved now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is with the `(** a)` syntactic sugar. The thing is that `(elem b)` is just the partial application of elem, that is:

```
(elem b) == (\xs -> elem b xs)
```

However when we use back ticks to make elem infix, we get a special syntax for infix operators which works like this:

```
(+ a) == (\ b -> b + a)
(a +) == (\ b -> a + b)
```

So therefore,

```
(`elem` xs) == (\a -> a `elem` xs) == (\ a -> elem a xs)
```

while

```
(elem xs) == (\a -> elem xs a)
```

So in the latter case your arguments are in the wrong order, and that is what is happening in your code.

Note that the `(** a)` syntactic sugar works for all infix operators except `-` since it is also a prefix operator. This exception from the rule is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454559/currying-subtraction/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210182/the-difference-between-1-and-1).

Comment: So how about the case of **isInfixOf**?

Comment: @manuzhang, the arguments also get in the opposite order for `isInfixOf`, just apply the same reasoning as in the answer. I thought about editing in that case but it is just copy paste what I said with `elem` replaced with `isInfixOf`.

Comment: @HaskellElepant Thx I've got it. The opposite ways could be `any (elem [1,2,3])[[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]],[[1,2,5]]]` and `any (\`isInfixOf\` [1,2,3,4]) [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4,5]]`

Comment: If my answer helped, feel free to upvote or even accept the answer.

Comment: Of course and that's what I've done! I'm new to Haskell, have no knowledge of lambda function and still getting accustomed to functional programming. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Using back-ticks around a function name turns it into an infix operator. So

```
x `fun` y
```

is the same as

```
fun x y
```

Haskell also has operator sections, f.e. `(+ 1)` means `\x -> x + 1`.

So

```
(`elem` xs)
```

is the same as

```
\x -> x `elem` xs
```

or

```
\x -> elem x xs
```

or

```
flip elem xs
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called [partial application](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Partial_application).

`isInfixOf [1, 2, 3]` returns a function that expects one parameter.

`any (elem [1, 2]) [1, 2, 3]` is an error because you're looking for an element `[1, 2]`, and the list only contains numbers, so haskell cannot match the types.

Comment: But `any (elem [1, 2]) [[1,2],[1,2,3]]` won't do either

Comment: `elem [1, 2] [[1,2],[1,2,3]]` should typecheck, but as you say, `any (elem [1, 2]) [[1,2],[1,2,3]]` does not. I think what you want here is `any (elem [1, 2]) [[[1,2,3],[1,2,4]],[[1,2,5]]]` as you said in another comment. So you have a list of lists of lists.