# Apply a constant subtraction using map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I simply want to substract 1 from every list element in [1,2,3,4] like

```
map (-1) [1,2,3,4] -- does not work

map ((-)1) [1,2,3,4] -- gives [0,-1,-2,-3] which is "-listvalue" + 1

map (\x = x - 1) [1,2,3,4] -- what I want but so verbose

map (+ (-1)) [1,2,3,4] -- well :)

map (flip (-) 1) [1,2,3,4] -- I heard of flip before

(map . flip (-)) 1 [1,2,3,4] -- Kinda nice mapped substration composing thingy

map pred [1,2,3,4] -- OK cheated and won't help with -2
```

Do I miss a form which would be "correct" and / or what Mr. Haskell use?

Comment: duplicate of [Currying subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454559/currying-subtraction)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [subtract](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/subtract_f.html) function instead

```
map (subtract 1) [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 4):

You've run into a minor wart of Haskell's design.  The expression `(-1)` could in principle be interpreted in two ways:

1. A section that partially applies the subtraction operator to its second argument.
2. The application of the unary sign operator to the number `1`.

Haskell goes with #2.  To make up for this the `subtract` function is provided to cover case #1.